# How may I schedule a powershell script through task scheduler commnd line?

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-line-interface, scheduled-tasks

I am using below command line to schedule a ps1 script. I am able to schedule successfully but the ps1 script is not running. Is there something i am missing here or using wrong syntax

```
SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC DAILY /TN "MYTASK\posschedule" /TR "powershell.exe ` -noprofile -executionpolicy Unrestricted ` -file \\sqlserver.na.era.net\SW01\XOGRG\EIP\PS Data\Run_Refresh.ps1" /ST 18:22
```

Comment: What makes you think it's not running? What does the scheduler log say? Does the task account have access to `\\sqlserver.na.era.net\SW01\XOGRG\EIP\PS Data\Run_Refresh.ps1`? What happens if you run that command line manually? Put some logging into your powershell file and see what happens.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks for pointing account, how may I mention the correct account in the command line?

Comment: Easiest is to open up the windows scheduler and set it in the windows scheduler user interface. You should never put free text logins and passwords into scripts.

Comment: This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks  shows you the switches for `SCHTASKS`. But it seems like you should be using the windows scheduler user interface

Comment: i always use GUI to schedule a task, the problem is that i am working on a citrix machine and i do not have task scheduler GUI available in my program list.

Comment: See the reference above. You can use U and P switches to provide run time credentials when you create the task.